# jbake plugin requires maven upgrade in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jbake

I'm using a maven plugin in my POM file.  When I build the project, I get an error:

```
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal br.com.ingenieux:jbake-maven-plugin:0.0.9:generate (default-cli) on project uts-documentation: The plugin br.com.ingenieux:jbake-maven-plugin:0.0.9 requires Maven version 3.1.1 -> [Help 1]`
```

My embedded maven version is 3.0.4.  How can I update to the required version without installing a separate instance of maven (would like to avoid that if possible)?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a separate Maven install?  That if certainly the easier approach to upgrading Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to a more recent Eclipse version will bring an updated embedded version of Maven.  For example the Eclipse Luna installation that I am running has Maven 3.2.1 embedded.

Comment: yes thanks.  I did eventually have to update to Luna, which was painful.  I did manage to get the 1.5 maven plugin installed (which embeds maven 3.1) via 'Install New Software' (it depends on the google 'guava' library, but then when it completed the installation and restarted by entire workspace was blown away.